# How to install zip2john on MacOS?

Tags: macos, installation

I am using MacOS and have installed John the Ripper using brew (john-jumbo) without any problem, but when I try to run `zip2john` I get:

`zsh: command not found: zip2john`

I've found only about how to install John the Ripper on MacOS, but not zip2john, so, how can I install zip2john on MacOS?

Comment: Although `john` is a security, how to install things is not a security issue.